# UIScrollView zoom out issue (IOS 8 GM)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming, ios8

I've been struggling on an issue with my `UIScrollView` for quite a long time now.
Basically, it's a simple zoomable `UIScrollView` that displays an `UIImageView`.

When the image is zoomed out at the maximum, we I release my pinch gesture, the animation is weird and does not smoothly zooms in to the minimum zoom scale.

It is actually reproducible in Apple's example at: [PhotoScroller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html)
Zoom out to the maximum an image and you will see the issue.

I tracked it down to being an extra call to layoutSubviews that is made in iOS 8 (iOS 7 works perfectly).

Has anybody encountered this issue, and if so, found a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix it by calling [self. layoutSubviews] in my scrollViewDidZoom method. It's sort of a hack, but it seems to have solved my problem.
This may help:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    [self layoutSubviews];
}
```

Override layoutSubviews to center content

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

// center the image as it becomes smaller than the size of the screen
CGSize boundsSize = super.bounds.size;
CGRect frameToCenter = imageView.frame;

// center horizontally
if (frameToCenter.size.width < boundsSize.width){
    frameToCenter.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - frameToCenter.size.width) / 2;
}
else {
    frameToCenter.origin.x = 0;
}
// center vertically
if (frameToCenter.size.height < boundsSize.height){
    frameToCenter.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - frameToCenter.size.height) / 2;
}
else {
    frameToCenter.origin.y = 0;
}
imageView.frame = frameToCenter;
}
```

Comment: Nice catch, I was having the same issue myself. However, you should not call layoutSubviews directly. Documentation says:

"You should not call this method directly. If you want to force a layout update, call the setNeedsLayout method instead to do so prior to the next drawing update. If you want to update the layout of your views immediately, call the layoutIfNeeded method".

I added the centering code to a separate method, and call that instead in the scrollViewDidZoom method

Answer (score 4):

The fix from @Jonah solved a similar issue for me, but it is important to not call layoutSubviews directly.

You can achieve a similar and safer effect with the following code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self setNeedsLayout]; // triggers a layout update during the next update cycle
    [self layoutIfNeeded]; // lays out the subviews immediately
}
```

See Apple's UIView docs for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews